# How to generate random number between (30 - 15n) and (30 +16n) (inclusive)?

Tags: random

I am working on a homework problem that asks me to write a simple program that simulates a fighting game that randomly generates damages for three attacks.  The first two simply generate a random number between 28-32 (inclusive).  However, the last attack is a charged attack. The user is asked to input the number of seconds they want the attack to be charged for and this number affects the damage output.  This charged attack must generate a random number between (30 - 15n) and (30 + 16n) (inclusive) with n being the number of seconds charged. If the user chooses 0 seconds, then the attack will always output 30.  If they input 1, then the range would be between 15 and 46 damage. If they input 3, then the range would be between -15 and 78 damage.

I am not sure how to go about writing the charged attack.  I am sure its fairly simple but I am new at programming.  Could I get some help on how to approach this?

Here is what I have written so far:

```
    //Variable Declaration
    int atkCharge, atk1, atk2, atk3;

    //Getting user input for how long the attack will be charged for
    System.out.println("Slotherius chooses Triple Claw Slash!");
    System.out.print("How many seconds do you wish to charge the attack?  ");
    atkCharge = scnr.nextInt();

    //Genrating attack damages 
    atk1 = randGen.nextInt(5) + 28;
    atk2 = randGen.nextInt(5) + 28; 
atk3 = //TODO: generate charged attack

System.out.println(atk1); //temp test code
System.out.println(atk2); //^^
System.out.println(atk3);




}
```

}

Comment: Start by figuring out how to calculate a random number between A and B. If you can figure out how to calculate a random number between 0 (inclusive) and X (exclusive), which most runtimes have classes or functions for, you can use that to generate between A and B with the formula `A + rnd(B - A + 1)`, then all you have to do is calculate A and B according to the lower and upper bound formulas you had.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it thorougly at the moment, but if you are allowed to use [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--), I think something among the following lines would work:

```
  int min = 30 - 15*n;
  int max = 30 + 16*n;
  int range = max - min + 1;

  int atk3 = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
```

Basically what this does is first creating two variables as described in your case. After that, we define a range between zero and the maximum value minus the minimum value, adding 1 for the inclusiveness.

Then, we use `Math.random()` to generate a number between 0 and 1, which we multiply by the range. This gives us a distribution between 0 and the range. Lastly, we transpose this whole distribution by the minimum value, shifting it either left of right on the 'axis', as it were, depending on the sign of `min`.

Comment: You should use `nextInt(bound)` rather than floating point math and casting.

Comment: @pjs True; see https://community.oracle.com/message/6596485#thread-message-6596485 for an explanation. Doesn't change the general point, though.